# how to return a spread object in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a custom hook in react with typescript, and I need to return a spread of the state, when I use the `<T extends object>` it works correctly, but I need to specify that this object has string values and this causes that when returning 2 or more objects, values, functions, etc. I get the following error

**Error:**

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ reset: () => void; }
```

**Interface:**

```
interface IState {
    [key:string]: string;
};
```

**Function:**

```
const myFunction = (initialState:IState) => {
    const [state,setState] = useState(initialState)
    const reset = () => setFormState( initialState );
    return { reset, ...state }
}
```

**File with the import:**

```
const {
        name, ■ Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ reset: () => void; }'.
        reset,
    } = useForm({
        name: 'hello',
    });
```

**when I only do return `{ ...state }` this error does not appear, and if I add more, the interface of each one appears in the error**

Comment: Your object spread is fine. I guess that `myFunction` and `useForm` are the same thing, in your example? Then the problem is in the `state` variable, which does not contain what you think it does. What is the return type of the `useState()` function?

Comment: You mean this? useState<IState>(initialState),

Comment: Yes, what does this function return?

Comment: In this case it returns the state which will be of type IState, and the function (state:IState) => void, these inside an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You still have to specify that the `name` property exists:

### Solution

#### Interface:

```
interface IState {
    [key:string]: string;
};
```

#### Function (actual change is here):

```
const useForm = <T extends IState>(initialState: T) => {
    const [state,setState] = useState(initialState)
    const reset = () => setFormState( initialState );
    return { reset, ...state }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
const {
    name,
    reset,
} = useForm({
     name: 'hello',
});
```

Comment: thanks, i was trying and it didn't work because i kept useState<IState>, but now i change it to <T> and it works perfect